# Can iPad/Safari Pretend to be a Different Browser to Avoid Nag Screens?

Tags: ipad, ios, safari, customization, web-browser

I'm doing more and more of my web browsing on my iPad these days. One of the downsides is that many of the sites I frequent force me to click through a "please install our iPad app" nag screen before allowing me to visit the site. At first it was just a few sites. Now it's becoming almost intolerable.

Apps have their place. I love Pinball, Words with Friends, Pages, Mail, Angry Birds, and Sling Player as much as the next guy. But if I have to install an app for every site I visit on a regular basis, I'm going to have to install like a dozen apps. Is there a way to get the iPad version of Safari to hide the fact that it's an iPad when communicating with web servers so as to prevent these nag screens from showing? If not, I'm going to have to revert back to doing all (most) my browsing on my laptop and iMac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Atomic Web](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/atomic-web-browser-full-screen/id347929410?mt=8) browser, it's UI is a little shoddy and not iPad3 retina ready, but the features are great. It can change the user agent to pretend to be other browsers, download files and then save them to Dropbox, and has a full screen mode.

You might also try [Google Chrome for iOS](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/mobile/ios.html), but I'm not sure if what User Agent that sends, I know it uses Webkit for rendering.

Comment: thanks, Garrow. I'll check these products out. I'd give you an up-vote but site says I need more reputation points first.

Comment: aha... ok, done.